# Need Help with Virtual box thru USB

Tags: virtualbox

All

I would like to use my USB as a virtual drive for virtual box because I have very little space on my laptop and can't afford to clear some space. Also, I would like to keep the iso file in the USB. Could someone please assist me?

BTW: Whenever I try to find the USB in the file manager on Virtual box I don't see it.

I am very quick to reply usually within 5mins.

Thanks,

Comment: To access your USB drive from a VB guest you must first add it as a USB device in the VBox Manager settings for the guest. You must do this while the guest is down. When you bring the guest up you can mount the usb drive into your guest file system and use it as you would any other file space. Look here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB

Comment: You may not know that after installation, you can discard the installer iso. Once it has done its good work you won't need it again.

Comment: I want to use my USB as the virtual storage so that I have the .vdk file on the USB instead of on the laptop SSD.

Comment: When you create the disk you can specify the location. There is a browse button where you name the disk.  If you have mounted the USB to your host file system you can put the virtual disk there. If you have already created the disk, you can move it using the vboxmanage CLI application. You may be able to do it with the GUI manager but I've never done it that way.

Comment: That is the problem I have my USB plugged in but don't see it when I click browse. If there is a way to do it through terminal what are the commands? When  I move the .vldk file it tells me that the file is missing. When I try to readjust the path to the USB it says I can't.

Comment: So click browse in the VirtualBox Gui Manager? On the host side? Do you mean within the guest?

Comment: There are three access points and it's not clear to me which one you're talking about. 1)The GUI manager USB pane in the VM's Settings dialog; 2) The GUI Manager Storage pane; 3) the Guest file browser. The one to check first is the #1. Is this the one you're referring to when you say "click browse"?  There is a little '+' icon.

Comment: I am talking about option 2 where the gui tells you to create a virtual drive, I would like the virtual drive to be on my USB.

Comment: Oh I thought we were talking about a previously created drive. What is the host system? Are you running VirtualBox on Windows or Linux or Mac or...  The file browsing dialog is determined by the host operating system. In Windows, I find mounted USBs in the "This PC" category. It can be hard to find. In Ubuntu, the file browser is more simple and direct. If the USB is mounted you will find it at the mount point. If you are on a Mac then I don't know. It's been a while since I was on a Mac.

Comment: I am on Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon. I can not see the mounted USB on the left pane where I choose the drive I just see home and /.

Comment: In my MATE 18.04, my left pane shows the items from the Places pane of the caja browser - the default file browser for MATE.
Can you expand that '/' node? If not, you could try adding a symlink in your home directory. (ln -s <usbmountpoint> /home/ameen/usb) where 'ameen' is the name of your home directory, and then restarting VirtualBox.  --

Comment: Are you sure the USB is mounted and you have access to it? Can you open it? Can you create a file on it?

Comment: Yes if I go to the normal file manager I can access it and store things on it.

Comment: Could it be a permission although I highly doubt it?

Comment: To be clear: if you click on the '/' node in your left pane, there is no response?

Comment: You will get more information using the vboxmanage command line client. This link shows the command to create the drive. https://nakkaya.com/2012/08/30/create-manage-virtualBox-vms-from-the-command-line/.
 If the command fails you will likely get an informative error. The GUI is a pretty and over-simplified interface to the VirtualBox tool. You will want to look into the vboxmanage command anyway at some point. Now seems like just the time.Here's the manual section on vboxmanage. It is well worth exploring. 
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html

Comment: actually, it says computer then inside of that it says "/" when I click on that it brings up a whole bunch of files.

Comment: Thanks for your help Stephen I found a solution and things are running fine now.

Comment: Please share Ameen. Write your solution as an answer and then accept it. Other people may come to your question and will want to know what you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was simple, I installed a wrong version of vbox it was the one from the website. I uninstalled it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge^C
```

This will get rid of all the necessary files but will leave the file in the home directory.

Then use this command to install the right vbox version:

```
apt install virtualbox-qt virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-ext-pack
```

As you will see the new vbox looks much better and allows you to choose any drive as your virtual hard drive.